# In org-mode, disable numbering of sections, subsections, etc

Tags: latex, org-mode

I'm constructing an org-mode document that I want to export to LaTeX. However, I don't want the sections and subsections to be numbered (e.g. I want to generate `\section*` rather than `\section`). I expect that there's an `options` setting that I can put in the header of my file, but what I've tried so far - `#+options: unnumbered` - hasn't done anything useful.

Comment: Pretty sure I wanted this as well, my OPTIONS are `#+OPTIONS: toc:nil author:nil num:nil ':t` see if any of these help :)

Comment: @DaveF I use most of those as well - the only one I wasn't using was `':t`, but that doesn't seem to change the section numbering behavior. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I found an approach that seems to work. The org-mode documentation for export options mentions that you can use the `num` option to "toggle section numbers" and that "when set to number N, Org numbers only those headlines at level N or above." So I added `#+options: num:0` to the header of my document and that seems to do the trick.